# Best way to fetch HTTP Requests then proccess HTML response

Tags: php, python, c, curl, domdocument

I'm working on a project which needs to import data from other websites, then process this response to be able to store it on the database and compare it with other results.

most of these websites doesn't supply json nor xml feeds, so I found my self forced to fetch HTML documents.

First I started to fetch them with CURL and process the response with PHP DomDocument & Xpath. But as I noticed that the process may be very slow to be done. So I started to search for another solution which may be faster and more reliable even if it's using another language like : python, ruby, perl, C etc...

Code example :

> This is Just a test code. before starting the project.

**Init CURL:**

```
public function curlInit($connId, $url , $postString){
    $this->multiConn[$connId] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($this->multiConn[$connId], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->multiConn[$connId], CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($this->multiConn[$connId], CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');

    curl_setopt($this->multiConn[$connId],CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
}
```

**Exec the requests :**

```
public function multiExec(){
    $this->multiAddHandler();
    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($this->multiHanler, $running);
    } while ($running);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($this->multiConn as $key => $v){
        $this->multiRespose[$key] = curl_multi_getcontent($v);
    }
}
```

This the code for executing the requests :

```
public function parse(){
            // first fetch & process the categories
    $this->getCategoryElementList("li");
            // then fetch all events on each category.
    $this->curl->multiExec();
            // parse the events response
    $this->processEvents();
            // after that i have to parse the details of each event.
}
```

**Now, parsing the HTML response :**

```
public function getCategoryElementList($tag){
    foreach($this->categoryIdsArr as $group){
        $domElement = $this->getElementById($group);

        $catList = $domElement->childNodes;
        $this->categoryElementList[] = $catList;

        foreach($catList as $cat){
            // temp Var , to check if the subcat_id is autogenerated, so don't init a curl connection for it
            $autoGenSubCatIds = array();
            if($cat->nodeName == 'li'){
                // -- Getting the category name -- //
                $catNameSapn = $this->searchElement($cat, "span", "class", "nav-special-name");

                if(empty($catNameSapn->item(0)->nodeValue)){
                    $catNameSapn = $this->searchElement($cat, "span", "class", "nav-region-name");
                }

                if(isset($catNameSapn->item(0)->nodeValue)){
                    $_categoryName = $catNameSapn->item(0)->nodeValue;
                }
                // autogenerate subcat_id if not exists 
                if($catNameSapn->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeName == 'a'){
                    $aTag = $catNameSapn->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->getAttribute("href");
                    $aTag = split("/",$aTag);
                    $_categoryId = $aTag[4];
                }elseif($catNameSapn->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeName == '#text'){
                    $tempId = 0;
                    array_walk(str_split($_categoryName), function($value, $index) use (&$tempId){
                        $tempId += ord($value);
                    });
                    $_categoryId = ($tempId);
                    $autoGenSubCatIds[] = $tempId;
                }
                // -- End getting the category name -- //
                $this->arrRes['category'][$_categoryId]['category_name'] = $_categoryName;
                $this->arrRes['category'][$_categoryId]['category_id'] = $_categoryId;

                $subCats = $cat->getElementsByTagName("a");
                foreach($subCats as $subCat){
                    $_subCategroyName = $subCat->nodeValue;
                    $aTag = $subCat->getAttribute("href");
                    $aTag = split("/",$aTag);
                    $_subCategoryId = $aTag[4];

                    $this->arrRes['category'][$_categoryId]['subcat'][$_subCategoryId]['subcat_name'] = $_subCategroyName;
                    $this->arrRes['category'][$_categoryId]['subcat'][$_subCategoryId]['subcat_id'] = $_subCategoryId;

                    if(!in_array($_subCategoryId, $autoGenSubCatIds))
                        $this->curl->curlInit($_subCategoryId, "https://********************.com", "Ids=$_subCategoryId&stId=4&page=0");

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**my question is not just about this code. I looking for the best way to make that count of connections and parse them.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process you describe involves mainly three parts :

1. fetching html documents from the internet
2. parsing the html
3. storing the parsed results in a database

First part of the process depends mainly on your network connection, the server's response time etc. Whatever language / techno you use won't make much of difference, since most of the time is spent in low-level system calls and network latency.

Third part is also mostly about your database engine performances, even if you may optimize things a bit here and there (how you build your queries, how you manage transactions, if you keep a persistent connection or reconnect each time etc).

This leaves you with the HTML parsing part. If it's well formed HTML there are a couple quite optimized parsers implemented in C that your language can make use of (ie Python's lxml binding to libxml2 and libxslt). There also are possible optimizations in how you write your code (in general - not talking about your above snippet which I didn't read) but how to do so depends on the exact language / technology you're using.

Now the point is that however optimized the parser and your own code, you'll still be bound to network and database performances. The only way to get better performances here is parallelizing the process as much as you can, with HTTP clients on as many nodes as possible feeding parsers on as many nodes as needed, themselves feeding the database.

We've solved a very similar problem in a Python app using Celery and RabbitMQ for the parallelization, balancing the load on 4 distinct "worker" nodes (plus one for the database and one for the Django / apache front-end), but there are just as good or even better solutions in most languages / technologies (MapReduce anyone ?).